# How to pass relative path to strings in Self-Extraction Directive file?

Tags: cmd, exe, inf, iexpress

I’m using IExpress to create a self-extracting / self-installing package (.EXE) and a Self-Extraction Directive file (.SED).
When moving the files from a test environment to a production one, I’ve noticed that the strings TargetName (target path and filename of the package) and SourceFiles0 (folder of the packaged files) were hardcoded, and so the creation of a new package failed because no folder/files were found in the “old” path.

```
[Version] 
Class=IEXPRESS 
SEDVersion=3 
[Options] 
PackagePurpose=InstallApp 
ShowInstallProgramWindow=1 
HideExtractAnimation=1 
UseLongFileName=1 
InsideCompressed=0 
CAB_FixedSize=0 
CAB_ResvCodeSigning=0 
RebootMode=N 
InstallPrompt=%InstallPrompt% 
DisplayLicense=%DisplayLicense% 
FinishMessage=%FinishMessage% 
TargetName=%TargetName% 
FriendlyName=%FriendlyName% 
AppLaunched=%AppLaunched% 
PostInstallCmd=%PostInstallCmd% 
AdminQuietInstCmd=%AdminQuietInstCmd% 
UserQuietInstCmd=%UserQuietInstCmd% 
SourceFiles=SourceFiles 
[Strings] 
InstallPrompt= 
DisplayLicense= 
FinishMessage= 
TargetName=C:\Test\MyPackage.exe 
FriendlyName= MyPackage 
AppLaunched= MyPackage.cmd 
PostInstallCmd=<None> 
AdminQuietInstCmd= 
UserQuietInstCmd= 
FILE0="MyPackage.cmd" 
FILE1=" MyPackage.ps1" 
[SourceFiles] 
SourceFiles0=C:\Test\MyChildFolder\ 
[SourceFiles0] 
%FILE0%= 
%FILE1%=
```

I’ve tried writing just the filename for TargetName or child folder for SourceFiles0, but I’ve got an error message.
The same goes for “.\” or ”%~dp0” or ”$(srcdir)\” (without the double quotes)
I’ve tried using [IExpress](https://ss64.com/nt/iexpress.html) GUI wizard and command-line tool.

Does anyone know how to pass a path relative to the .sed file itself to those strings?

Comment: As the SED seems almost identical to an INF file format, the only possible option I can think of, is to try using a DirID. In a .inf file the parent of that file is referenced  using the DirID `01`. If that doesn't work, the only other thing I would suggest is to dynamically write the SED, during the code run, so that the, then known, location is hardcoded.

Comment: @Compo, thanks for the suggestion. I've tried using "DirID01", "DirID 01", "%DirID01%", and "%01%" (without double quotes) and it didn't work. Could you please point me to the right use of it. I received this message: "The Key: Dir01 is not defined in SED file Strings section. Do you want to continue?  "

Comment: In an inf file, it is often just referenced as is, for example, if you wanted to use `infParent\subDir\destDir`, you'd use `01,subDir\destDir`, or `01,"subDir\destDir"`. Note the comma to seperate the DirID location from the remaining path string.

Comment: @Compo, first of all, thank you. This time I've got the following error message: "Unable to find 01,MyChildFolder\MyFile.FileExtension. Please check your packaged file list". Unfortunately, it seems to be reserved for inf files. However, I'll follow your advice by dynamically creating the sed files, and then executing iexpress.exe

Comment: _I knew it was a shot in the dark!_ Thanks for the feedback, .